# C++ constructor behave differently according to input, with help of template

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I'm trying to use the template to initialize an object. The code should assign s according to different parameters input, specifically "type". However, I can't get this to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// different discount

class Strategy {
public:
    virtual double GetResult(double) = 0;
};

class SellNormal: public Strategy {
public:
    double GetResult(double original) override {
        return original;
    }
};

class SellDiscount: public Strategy {
    double rate;
public:
    SellDiscount(double r){
        rate = r;
    }
    double GetResult(double original) override {
        return original * rate;
    }
};
class SellReturn: public Strategy {
    int fulfill;
    int reduce;
public:
    SellReturn(int f, int r): fulfill(f), reduce(r){}
    double GetResult(double original) override {
        return original - (int(original) / fulfill) * reduce;
    }
};
class SellContext{
    Strategy* s;
public:
    enum type{
        NORMAL,
        DISCOUNT,
        RETURN
    };
    template<typename ...Ts>
    SellContext(type t, Ts... args){
        switch(t){
        case NORMAL:
            s = new SellNormal();
            break;
        case DISCOUNT:
            // double
            s = new SellDiscount(args...);
            break;
        case RETURN:
            // int, int
            s = new SellReturn(args...);
            break;
        }
    }
    double getResult(double original){
        return s->GetResult(original);
    }
};
    
int main(){
    auto c1 = new SellContext(SellContext::type::NORMAL);
    auto c2 = new SellContext(SellContext::type::DISCOUNT, 0.8);
    auto c3 = new SellContext(SellContext::type::RETURN, 300, 100);
    cout << c1->getResult(1000);
    cout << c2->getResult(1000);
    cout << c3->getResult(1000);
}
```

It's telling me that C++ can't find the appropriate constructor. How should I deal with this elegantly? I know I could achieve this by overloading constructors with different parameters. But isn't that too verbose?

The errors are as below

```
s

trategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp: In instantiation of 'SellContext::SellContext(SellContext::type, Ts ...) [with Ts = {}]':
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:71:56:   required from here
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:57:17: error: no matching function for call to 'SellDiscount::SellDiscount()'
             s = new SellDiscount(args...);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:23:5: note: candidate: 'SellDiscount::SellDiscount(double)'
     SellDiscount(double r){
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:23:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:20:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr SellDiscount::SellDiscount(const SellDiscount&)'
 class SellDiscount: public Strategy {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:20:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:20:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr SellDiscount::SellDiscount(SellDiscount&&)'
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:20:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:61:17: error: no matching function for call to 'SellReturn::SellReturn()'
             s = new SellReturn(args...);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:35:5: note: candidate: 'SellReturn::SellReturn(int, int)'
     SellReturn(int f, int r): fulfill(f), reduce(r){}
     ^~~~~~~~~~
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:35:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:31:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr SellReturn::SellReturn(const SellReturn&)'
 class SellReturn: public Strategy {
       ^~~~~~~~~~
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:31:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:31:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr SellReturn::SellReturn(SellReturn&&)'
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:31:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp: In instantiation of 'SellContext::SellContext(SellContext::type, Ts ...) [with Ts = {double}]':
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:72:63:   required from here
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:61:17: error: no matching function for call to 'SellReturn::SellReturn(double&)'
             s = new SellReturn(args...);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:35:5: note: candidate: 'SellReturn::SellReturn(int, int)'
     SellReturn(int f, int r): fulfill(f), reduce(r){}
     ^~~~~~~~~~
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:35:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:31:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr SellReturn::SellReturn(const SellReturn&)'
 class SellReturn: public Strategy {
       ^~~~~~~~~~
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:31:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'double' to 'const SellReturn&'
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:31:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr SellReturn::SellReturn(SellReturn&&)'
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:31:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'double' to 'SellReturn&&'
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp: In instantiation of 'SellContext::SellContext(SellContext::type, Ts ...) [with Ts = {int, int}]':
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:73:66:   required from here
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:57:17: error: no matching function for call to 'SellDiscount::SellDiscount(int&, int&)'
             s = new SellDiscount(args...);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:23:5: note: candidate: 'SellDiscount::SellDiscount(double)'
     SellDiscount(double r){
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:23:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:20:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr SellDiscount::SellDiscount(const SellDiscount&)'
 class SellDiscount: public Strategy {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:20:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:20:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr SellDiscount::SellDiscount(SellDiscount&&)'
strategy_pattern_with_simple_factory.cpp:20:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Comment: Don't all constructors require default values in the declaration? Is that possible if you are using templates? I don't know enough about templates to comment on that.

Comment: Producing the error you describe would require a [mre].  The code you show does not produce the error you show.

Comment: `template<type, typename ...Ts>`. It looks like `type` shouldn't be there at all. `type` is not a template parameter. It's the type of the first argument to the constructor.

Comment: What's with all the bare `new`?

Comment: @DrewDormann Thanks for commenting. I thought it was too naive to provide those since the main purpose was to create the instances. I didn't want those to distract from the main question. But I would add them here. Sorry about that

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica That was just to show how I may use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `Strategy` must have a `virtual` destructor since you'll be destroying instances via base class pointers.

It looks like you are trying to use `type` as some sort of tag and you can't explicitly supply template parameters to the constructor. That would be a template parameter to the class itself - and `SellContext` is not a class template, so using tags is a good idea. They do need to be of different types though, so I suggest creating separate tag types and also to make the pointer into a smart pointer.

Example:

```
#include <memory>

class SellContext{
    std::unique_ptr<Strategy> s; // <- smart pointer

public:
    // tag types and tag instances:
    static constexpr struct NORMAL {} normal_tag{};
    static constexpr struct DISCOUNT {} discount_tag{};
    static constexpr struct RETURN {} return_tag{};

    // The constructors you need. No `switch` needed:
    template<class... Args>
    SellContext(NORMAL, Args&&... args) :
        s(std::make_unique<SellNormal>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {}

    template<class... Args>
    SellContext(DISCOUNT, Args&&... args) :
        s(std::make_unique<SellDiscount>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {}
    
    template<class... Args>
    SellContext(RETURN, Args&&... args) :
        s(std::make_unique<SellReturn>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {}

    double getResult(double original){
        return s->GetResult(original);
    }
};
```

Using them would then be done like this:

```
int main(){
    auto c1 = std::make_unique<SellContext>(SellContext::normal_tag);
    auto c2 = std::make_unique<SellContext>(SellContext::discount_tag, 0.8);
    auto c3 = std::make_unique<SellContext>(SellContext::return_tag, 300, 100);
    
    std::cout << c1->getResult(1000) << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WscWxTEW5)

Using *constexpr-if*:

```
#include <type_traits>

class SellContext{
    std::unique_ptr<Strategy> s;

public:
    static constexpr struct NORMAL {} normal_tag{};
    static constexpr struct DISCOUNT {} discount_tag{};
    static constexpr struct RETURN {} return_tag{};

    template<class Tag, class... Args>
    SellContext(Tag, Args&&... args) {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<NORMAL, Tag> || 
                      std::is_same_v<DISCOUNT, Tag> ||
                      std::is_same_v<RETURN, Tag>);

        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<NORMAL, Tag>)
            s = std::make_unique<SellNormal>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<DISCOUNT, Tag>)
            s = std::make_unique<SellDiscount>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<RETURN, Tag>)
            s = std::make_unique<SellReturn>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    double getResult(double original){
        return s->GetResult(original);
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ta4vc6Y3d)

Since the current constructors of the `Strategy` objects are all different, you could make it even simpler and remove the tags:

```
class SellContext{
    std::unique_ptr<Strategy> s;

public:
    SellContext() : s(std::make_unique<SellNormal>()) {}
    SellContext(double x) : s(std::make_unique<SellDiscount>(x)) {}
    SellContext(double x, double y) : s(std::make_unique<SellReturn>(x, y)) {}

    double getResult(double original){
        return s->GetResult(original);
    }
};
```

```
int main(){
    auto c1 = std::make_unique<SellContext>();
    auto c2 = std::make_unique<SellContext>(0.8);
    auto c3 = std::make_unique<SellContext>(300, 100);

    std::cout << c1->getResult(1000) << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yd8dq697b)

Comment: Thanks Ted for answering this. I totally understand this could make it work. Is there any way to make it without overloading the constructor? That was the main reason I tried with template. BTW, I just edited the code provided for more info

Comment: @Coding-pupupu Sure, I added that as a second option under _using constexpr-if_.

Comment: Thanks so much! Let me study "constexpr-if" and "forward" for a bit and see if I need to bother you again. That was so helpful!

Comment: @Coding-pupupu Glad it helped and you're welcome!  You'll find a short description of _constexpr if_ [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/) (half-way down). There's also a chapter on [`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) and the special _forwarding references_ that allows for perfect forwarding of the arguments.